# Constructing vielbein from given metric: example: 2D spherical coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Usual relation between metric and vielbein are given by
\begin{align}
g^{\mu\nu} = e^{\mu}{}_a e^{\nu}{}_{b} \eta^{ab}
\end{align}
where $\eta^{ab}$ is flat, $\mu,\nu$ is curved, ($i.e$, diffeomorphism index : index related with coordinate change) and $a,b$ are  (Lorentz index).

I know that for given metric, vielbein form is not unique. Even though i want to construct vielbein and check above and inverse of above independently.

In the usual GR textbook, even though they mention vielbeins, for actual computation they just compute 1-forms (orthonormal basis) and obtain same results.

For example in sphere 
\begin{align}
ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 d\Omega^2 
\end{align}
and $e_r = dr$, $e_{\theta} = rd\theta $, $e_{\varphi} = r \sin(\theta) d\varphi$, then via cartan's formalism (via its structure equations), i can compute connection, Riemann tensor and so on.

What i want to know is process of computing vielbein of general given metric. (not necessarily be diagonal) 
Before generalizing i want to know some simple case.

Comment: Note that the choice of vielbein is far from unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general way is probably to look at it as a matrix equation, i.e.:
$$g = e^T \eta \,e,$$

and then simply manipulate this to find the components of the vielbein. Remember that they are quadratic matrices.

Comment: In terms of linear algebra: Finding the Eigensystem of $(g)$